# How do I echo a redirect in php?

Tags: php, redirect

Ok so I want to set something up where if an un-subscribed user joins my website they get redirected to a joining page but if they are a subscribed member they stay on the homepage.

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
// Make sure the user is logged in and sanitize the session
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $u = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo <- Need the code here
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect a user by settings a `Location` header:

```
header('Location: /newPage.php');
```

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) calls to `header()` must be made before any output.

To quote the docs on redirection:

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it
>   send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT
>   (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code
>   has already been set.

Comment: Does this automatically send a HTTP 302 ?

Comment: Cool this works, thanks man

Comment: It does indeed @kkaosninja - answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use header() to redirect the user.

```
header("Location: file.php");
```

No need to use exit() too.